# Uniqueness of solution to an integral equation on the half line

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

The equation in question is
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty f(y)(x+y)e^{-x^2/2-xy}\text{d}y$$ where $f: [0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$. It is not hard to see $f(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$ solves the equation. However, how would you prove the uniqueness (if it is unique..) of a solution to such an equation?

Answer (score 1):

it's the only smooth solution: write

$$
f(x) = e^{-x^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}
$$

now some integral/sum switcheroo together with coefficient comparison affords the desired result

EDIT: as pointed out by thomas the above method is unwieldy. new attempt: write

$$
f(x) = C(x)e^{-x^2/2}
$$

then by assumption

$$
C(x)e^{-x^2/2} = \int_{0}^{\infty}C(y)(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}dy \quad (*)
$$

the derivative of the right hand side is

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}C(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}]dy = \int_{0}^{\infty}C(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}]dy
\\
= C(y)(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}|_{y=0}^\infty - \int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}dy
\\
= -C(0)xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} - \int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}dy
$$

now - by $(*)$ - integrating over all $x$'s gives

$$
-C(0) = -C(0)\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx - \int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)\int_{0}^{\infty}(x+y)e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}dxdy
\\
= -C(0)[-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)[-e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}}]_{x=0}^{\infty}dy
\\
= -C(0) - \int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy
$$

or

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}C'(y)e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy = 0
$$

while the last equation is fulfilled trivially for $C=constant$, it conceivably has nontrivial solutions. one such can be constructed using alternating smooth bump functions.

i'll leave the thoughts on convergence to you =)

EDIT: wrong, nothing guarantees that such a constructed function would be a solution. it's still preferable to use Taylor expansion or fourier analysis...

Comment: The switcheroo is not that apparent to me. On the right hand side you end up with $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(\int_0^\infty y^n(x+y)e^{-(x+y)^2/2}\text{d}y\right),$$ and these integrals do not look really friendly to me.

Comment: @suissidle: would it be possible to provide more detail?

Comment: try partial integration to get rid of the powers of $y$. btw what hat did you pull the $e^{-y^2/2}$ term out of?

Comment: Doing that you will end up with confluent hypergeometric functions, at least that is what Mathematica tells me. Not sure how much that helps you. @suissidle The $e^{-y^2/2}$ came from substituting $f(y)=e^{-y^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n y^n$, like you suggested.

Comment: right, i was sloppy there, see edited post

Comment: thanks, your post gave me much inspiration

Comment: in the middle of your new post: after integrating by parts the $(x+y)$ factor should disappear
$$
-g(y)e^{-(x+y)^2/2}\big\vert_{y=0}^\infty - \int_{0}^{\infty}g'(y)e^{-(x+y)^2/2}\text{ d}y
$$
taking you back to my previous argument (with $g(x)=C(x)$)

Comment: the bump function construction yields a nontrivial non-analytic smooth solution. first construct a function $\phi_a$ that is constant $1$ on $[0,a]$, constant $-1$ on $[2a,\infty)$ and smooth, decreasing in between. then vary $a\ge0$ so that $I_a=\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi_a(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=0$. this is possible since $I_0<0$ but $I_a>0$ for $a$ large enough

Comment: You're completely right, very sloppy of me. Thank you for all your input.

Comment: np i enjoyed it

Comment: One last question, since I'm not that comfortable with the bump functions. Do you think your method would also allow you to construct a function $g(x)$ that is strictly positive?

Comment: sorry let me clarify something: the 'gaussian' integral of $C'$ is only a _necessary_ condition (because it's a conserved quantity, not a functional identity). i don't know how to show that such a constructed function is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it helps, but you can write:

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty f(y) \, (x+y) \, e^{-x^2/2-xy}\mathrm{d}y=e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^\infty f(y) \, (x+y) \, e^{-xy}\mathrm{d}y$$
$$=x \, e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^\infty f(y) \, e^{-xy}\mathrm{d}y + e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^\infty y \, f(y) \, e^{-xy}\mathrm{d}y$$

Then, if F is Laplace transform of f, i.e. $F(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x y} \, f(y) \mathrm{d}y$, your equation is:
$$ f(x) = x \, e^{-x^2/2} F(x) - e^{-x^2/2} F'(x)$$
Or,
$$e^{x^2/2}f(x)=xF(x) - F'(x)$$

Comment: Looks like a useful transformation, however also for these type of equations I am not familiar with uniqueness theorems..